# How to handle exceptions in synchronous channels for spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

I have the following configuration

```
       <int:channel id="ftpChannel"/> 
<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="ftpInbound"
    channel="ftpChannel"
    session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
    charset="UTF-8"
    local-directory="file:${paths.root}"
    delete-remote-files="true"
    temporary-file-suffix=".writing"
    remote-directory="${file.ftpfolder}"

    filter="compositeFilterRemote"
     preserve-timestamp="true"
     auto-startup="true">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
<int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="ftpOutbound"
    channel="ftpChannel"
    session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
    charset="UTF-8"
    remote-file-separator="/"
    auto-create-directory="true"
    remote-directory="${file.ftpfolder}" 
    use-temporary-file-name="true"
     temporary-file-suffix=".writing">
    <int-ftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
         <bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
            <property name="onSuccessExpression" value="payload.delete()" />
          </bean>
    </int-ftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
  </int-ftp:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

I want to add error handling to this. How should I go about it? This is a direct channel and so runs in the same thread. If I throw exceptions from my code for eg in the Custom file filter, where can I catch it and return a uniform response. Also what can I do to catch runtime exceptions??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `error-channel` to the inbound adapter's `<poller/>` and an `ErrorMessage` will be sent to that channel when an exception is thrown.

If the exception occurs before the message is created (such as in your filter), the payload will be the raw exception. If the exception occurs after the message is created and is being processed (such as an error in the outbound adapter in your case), the payload is a `MessagingException` with `failedMessage` and `cause` properties.